# Twisted ResponseFailed error when using scrapy shell

Tags: python, scrapy, runtime-error, twisted, screen-scraping

I'm hitting the error

> twisted.web._newclient.ResponseFailed:
>   []

when running `scrapy shell https://www.macupdate.com` while other websites are being scraped fine.

I'm trying to debug it but I have no idea what exactly is causing this error.

Really appreciate the help!

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to provide an answer (or even know what you're trying to do).  Provide a complete, self-contained example that produces the problem.  Then explain how the observed behavior differs from the desired behavior.

Comment: With the added information, I can reproduce _an_ error but not this one.  That said, I'm not sure this is really a stackoverflow question.  It might be a superuser question or it might just be a bug report for the scrapy project.